# как php выдает страницу, соответствующий файл которой отсутствует на диске?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Разбираюсь в чужом проекте. Через ссылку на стартовой странице открываю адрес типа:
https://companysite.ru/path/to/page_112.php
При этом на диске нет соответствующего ссылке файла "page_112.php". 
Прошу пояснить, каким образом php, получая запрос к несуществующему файлу, может выдавать необходимую страницу. Есть ли название у такого приема? Поиск в инете по обиходным словам дается туго.

P.S. с подсказки в комментарии нашел, что переадресация, в случае отсутствия целевых файла или папки, может выполняться с помощью директив *RewriteCond, RewriteRule* , прописываемых в .htaccess

Comment: Поиск в интернете по словам - url rewrite, mod_rewrite, ЧПУ

Comment: @u_mulder, спасибо